# Is the Burst Laser I superior to the Dual Lasers?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

In my haste a bought a **Burst Laser I** before fully examining the stats, only to realize afterwards that it was inferior to the **Dual Lasers** I already own. The part I find unusual is that the **Burst Laser 1** is worth *more* than the **Dual Lasers** even thought the **Dual Lasers** is superior to the **Burst Laser 1.** I find this very unusual, so I thought maybe there was something about the **Burst Laser I** that wasn't listed on the stats, but after doing some testing and crawling through the internet I can't find anything that would suggest the **Burst Laser** is superior than the **Dual Lasers**.

[The stats for the weapons can be found on the wiki](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons).

Is there some hidden stat that makes the **Burst Laser I** superior to the **Dual Lasers**, or is the odd price difference between the **Burst Laser I** and the **Dual Lasers** just that, odd?

Comment: I tried to copy the weapon stats over, but due to SE lack of table support it just wouldn't work.

Comment: I suspect the price difference is a balance issue so the stealth ship doesn't have too much scrap if they choose to sell them at a store.

Comment: Firing a Burst Laser against a ship with 1 shield, one hit drops the shield and the other hits the hull. Does the Dual Laser have the same effect or do they both hit the shield?

Comment: @Hand-E-Food same effect.

Comment: The only difference between the two weapons is that the bursts take more energy, longer to charge, and are worth more.

Comment: Is this a trick question? Dual Lasers cost 1 energy to operate instead of 2, and charge in 10 seconds instead of 11, all for the same damage. If that's not better, then I don't know what is.

Comment: @Hackworth: Yes, except the Burst Lasers are worth double the value of the Dual Lasers, which just doesn't make any sense unless there's something about the burst lasers I'm missing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is no, the burst laser 1 is not superior to dual lasers. That's also the long answer. The description of dual lasers makes them sound bad, but they really aren't, compared to weapons of similar strength.

Comment: There is no weapon better than the dual laser, at least until sector 7 or so when your weapons slots start to fill out.  2 shots for 1 power?  With 10 second charge time?  It doesn't get better than that.  The only downside to them is that they're only available OEM with certain ships.